# FindDuplicate program not having right outcome

Tags: java, arrays

My code is intended to take user input n value for example 1 3 6 6 3 and identify if there's a duplicate number. Print out True if there is one and False otherwise.

```
int a = args.length;
int[] list = new int[a];
for (int i = 0; i < a; i++) {
  int n = Integer.parseInt(args[i]);
  list[i] = n;
}
for (int i = 0; i < a; i++) {
  for (int j = i + 1; j < a; j++) {
    if (list[i] == list[j]) {
      System.out.print("True");
    } else {
      System.out.print("False");
      return;
    }
  }
}
```

The code, in my opinion, looks fine but when I tested a couple of values it's having issues that I don't know how to solve.
For example, for test case 4 5 2 1 2 it prints out false

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are currently printing *false* and returning once you find two numbers that are not equal. The other pairs are not compared.

Move printing *false* to the end of the code.

```
for(int i = 0; i < a; i++){
    for(int j = i + 1; j < a; j++){
        if(list[i] == list[j]){
          System.out.print("True");
          return;
        }
    }
}
System.out.print("False"); //Print once you've seen all the pairs
```